# MATLAB - How to find the last row in a column with the value greater than zero (or before sequence of NaNs)?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, find, row

I have columns of values that decrease to ~1, after which all remaining values are NaNs. For example:

```
10    10
8     9
6     8
5     7
3     5
1     2
NaN   1
NaN   NaN
```

What I need is the row number of each column immediately before the sequence of NaNs, or the last positive integer in the sequence. Row 6 and row 7 in the example above.

While a loop can probably be used to find the desired row of each column, I'm unable to identify the correct command to find this row. I attempted using `find 'last'` without success. Please advise the best way to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: `[R, C] = find(isnan(), 'first')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your matrix is `a`, you can use

```
 sum(isfinite(a))

ans =
     6     7
```

this means that for the first col it is the 6th row, and for second col it is the 7th row that have the last non-NaN values.

this is alternatively the same: `sum(~isnan(a))`...

Comment: Many thanks @natan. How can I then change these found NaNs to zeros?

Comment: if `a` is your matrix then `a(isnan(a(:))=0` will do.

Comment: Thanks. However this changes all NaNs to 0 rather than the first in each column (i.e. of row 6 and 7 respectively).

Comment: well that wasnt clear from the question. Also, this is not the way SO works, I prefer you ask a new question, and\or try to take the tools that I showed you to try and answer that yourself.